# Same sequence for id's in multiple entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Can I use same sequence for id's in muliple entities?

Now I get for example

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance  of
>   org.cometd.hibernate.User altered from 12 to 3

Comment: yes, only requirement for Id is it has to be unique for that entity/table

Comment: Do you have any snippet for me? I use Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and I have this exception.

Comment: I found the mistake. It was not the sequence, but a setter for the Id. It lacked a "this"